# PHP. How Can I check ALL array

Tags: php, arrays, strlen

I have this code:

```
$data[1] = "blablabla";
$data[2] = "blablablabla";
if (strlen($data) < 10)
{
  // doing...
}
```

In this code I want to check all elements from array. How to do it?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Do you want to do something if ANY of your array elements is less than 10 characters in length? If they are ALL shorter? Or something else?

Comment: I want to chaeck all my array elements. If one of them is shorter then 10 symbols...it have to return error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach ($data as $element) {
    if (strlen($element) < 10) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

If you want to modify the data, use a reference (add a `&` before `$element`):

```
foreach ($data as &$element) {
    if (strlen($element) < 10) {
        // Do something to $element
        $element = "something else";
    }
}
```

If you don't want to use references directly, you can use a standard `for` loop with an indexer:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
    if (strlen($data[$i]) < 10) {
        // Do something with $data[$i]
        $data[$i] = "something else";
    }
}
```

Comment: And If I want to modify some elements?

Comment: `foreach ($data as &$element) {` then use `$element` as if it was `$data[blarg]`

Comment: It's not a pointer.  It's a reference.  http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php

Comment: you can also use foreach($data as $i=>&$element){ instead of "for()"

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_walk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) function of PHP. There are many examples on the linked PHP manual page.

Also take a look at [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i = 0;$i < count($data);$i++){
    if (strlen($data[$i]) < 10){
        // process
    }
}
```